# Foreach won't return elements of char list

Tags: c#, list, foreach, char

So im making this hangman game, as Im trying to learn C# but now im stuck with System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.Char]. What im trying to do is to save wrong answers into List nepravilne, look into functions izpis and igra

```
class Program
{
    static private int _sccore;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string beseda;
        int dolzina;
        bool play=true;
        char input;

        do
        {
            beseda = izberi_besedo();
            dolzina = beseda.Length;
            igra(beseda, dolzina);

            Console.WriteLine("Vnesite Y za nadaljevanje ali N za zakljucitev igre.");
            input = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (input.Equals('y'))
            {
                play = true;
                Console.WriteLine("play {0}",play);
            }
            if (input.Equals('n'))
            {
                play = false;
                Console.WriteLine("play {0}", play);
            }
        } while (play == true);                         
    }

    static private string izberi_besedo() {
        string[] besede = { "voda", "ladija", "letalo", "motor", "klavir", "harmonika", "saksofon", "oklep", "penkalo", "tiskalnik", "miza", "copat", "krogla", "klobuk", "gumb", "harfa", "kontrabas", "mandarina", "les", "knjiga", "vlak", "vijak", "struna", "kozarec" };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int stevilka = rnd.Next(0, 23);
        string beseda = besede[stevilka];
        return beseda;
    }

    static private void igra (string beseda, int dolzina){

        int i, poizkusi = 0;
        int pravilne = 0;
        bool endloop = false;
        char crka;
        List<char> nepravilne = new List<char>();//declaring char list for wrong words

        string[] odkrite = new string[dolzina];

        for(i=0; i<dolzina; i++) { odkrite[i] = "_"; }

        do {

            izpis(odkrite,nepravilne); //izpis - function which returns just text, we are inputing list nepravilne, which are wrong answers
            vpis(out crka);

            if (!(beseda.Contains(crka)))//if word doesen't contain letter
            {
                poizkusi++;
                _sccore--;
                nepravilne.Add(crka);//add that letter to list
            }


            for (i = 0; i<dolzina; i++)
            {
                if (crka.Equals(beseda[i]))
                {
                    odkrite[i] = Convert.ToString(crka);
                    pravilne++;
                    _sccore++; 
                }  
            }
            Console.Clear();
            if (pravilne >= dolzina || poizkusi >= 4)endloop = true;
        } while (endloop==false);
     }

    static private void vpis(out char crka)
    {
        string vpis;
        bool stevilka=false, status;

        Console.WriteLine("\nVnesite crko za ugibanje besede");
        vpis = Console.ReadLine();

        stevilka = IsNumeric(vpis);

        if (vpis.Length == 1 && stevilka==false)
        {
            crka = Convert.ToChar(vpis);
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                status = false;
                if (vpis.Length!=1) Console.WriteLine("Vnesli ste prevec crk, poizkusite ponovno");
                if(stevilka==true) Console.WriteLine("Vnesli ste stevilko, poizkusite ponovno");
                vpis = Console.ReadLine();
                stevilka = IsNumeric(vpis);
                if (vpis.Length == 1 && stevilka == false)
                {
                    status = true;
                }
            } while (status==false);

            crka = Convert.ToChar(vpis);
        }

    }



    private static bool IsNumeric(string vpis)
    {
        int number;
        return int.TryParse(vpis, out number);
    }

    private static void izpis(string[] odkrite, List<char> nepravilne)
    {
        Console.Write("Rezultat {0} | ", _sccore);

        foreach (char element in nepravilne)//write out char elements which contain letter
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", nepravilne);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (string element in odkrite)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", element);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand (cannot read) the code. It's intent is quite obscure. Could you translate the names to understand what you're doing? If you add some explanation of what each part of your code does, it's easier to get help.

Comment: Yeah my bad, well lesson learned for next time to post comments when Im doing something in my language. Thank you for time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo in the following code, i.e I think you are intending to print the variable **element** in the loop and not **nepravilne**:

```
foreach (char element in nepravilne)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", nepravilne);
}
```

Should be as follows instead?

```
foreach (char element in nepravilne)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", element);
}
```

Comment: God bless you mate, thank you very much, I feel so stupid now

Comment: Don't worry! everyone has the right to be taught :)